# dojo - How to get node by Id if it has not been added to the dom yet?

Tags: javascript, templates, dom, dojo

I am working on a custom `dojo` widget that includes a `Dialog`.  The `Dialog` content is loaded as text from a template `html` file.  The issue I am having is that I need to add dom nodes to the `Dialog` content before the `Dialog` is added to the dom.

Here is my template (`DialogContent.html`):

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="printTitle">Map Title:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="printTitle" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" name="title" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="printOrientation">Page Orientation:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select id="printOrientation" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/FilteringSelect" name="orientation">
                        <option value="Letter ANSI A Landscape">Landscape</option>
                        <option value="Letter ANSI A Portrait">Portrait</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="printUnits">Scale Bar Units:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select id="printUnits" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/FilteringSelect" name="units">
                        <option value="Miles">Miles</option>
                        <option value="Kilometers">Kilometers</option>
                        <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
                        <option value="Meters">Meters</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="printLayers">Layers to Include in Legend:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                     <select id="printLayers" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/MultiSelect" name="layers"></select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div>
        <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="submit">OK</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then I load the template as text into my widget with `define([...,...,...,"dojo/text!./PrintWidget/templates/DialogContent.html"]...)`

This comes in as a string variable, but I need to add the options under `#printLayers` dynamically.  Because it is just a text string, I cannot work with it as a dom node.  When I use `domConstruct.toDom(dialogContent)` it gets converted to an actual dom node that I can work with, but because the dom node has not actually been added to the DOM at this point (it's just a javascript dom object), I can't access `#printLayers` via `dom.byId` or `dojo/query`.

How can I access `#printLayers` within my template in order to dynamically add `option` elements?

Comment: <label for="printLayers" data-dojo-attach-point="printLayers">Layers to Include in Legend:</label> and then you can access it in your widget this.printLayers

Comment: @Marius - for some reason I assumed that I couldn't use `data-dojo-attach-point` for this because it's not actually the template for the widget itself, but instead a template for a `Dialog` that the widget opens.  Thinking about it now, it doesn't really make a difference.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out the solution was related to order of operations.  I was unable to work with the dom node because it had not been added to the dom yet.  It was just a javascript object.  Once I created the `Dialog` and set the dom node as the `content` for the `Dialog`, the dom node was added into the dom and I could access `#printLayers` using `dom.byId("printLayers")`.